# Does government track wu transfer?

Tags: canada, money-transfer, money-market, china

I have been sending money to my family back in China over year now and probably sent 25000.

But last week I was trying to send it through wu agian and they put it on hold and decline saying it might be fraud.....  Person who word there said it might be because of limit  which I ask customer service and they said is not ( I am sure they know )

Anyway what can I do here ?

Should I use money gram instead or bank transfer ?

This is in Canada. I looked around on net but wasn't able to get any solid answer

If you can help that would be great

Thank you

Comment: They have perhaps blocked it as being suspicious... http://www.fintrac-canafe.gc.ca/publications/guide/Guide2/2-eng.asp